# How to construct a rational number sequence for any irrational number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that there exists an increasing/decreasing rational number sequence $(p_n)$ for any real number $x$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}p_n = x$. But how can we construct this sequence? Specifically, given $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, *how* can we construct $(p_n), p_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n = x$?

Comment: Consider $3$, $3.1$, $3.14$, $3.141$, $3.1415$, $3.14159$. ,...

Comment: For any integer denominator $b>0$, you can get "close" to $x$ by taking $p = a/b$ where $a$ is the largest integer such that
$$
\frac ab < x \iff a < bx.
$$
The larger $b$ is, the closer this $p$ will be to $x$.

Comment: How concrete an answer are you looking for? There are numbers for which it's impossible to "construct" such a sequence, if by "construct" you mean "have a procedure that lets you actually write down the nth rational number as a fraction of two concrete known integers". Chaitin's construction produces *extremely* pathological real numbers, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any diverging integer sequence $m_n$ and build

$$p_n=\dfrac{\lfloor x\,m_n\rfloor}{m_n}.$$

The "error" is bounded by $\dfrac1{m_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do it:

$a_n = \frac{\lfloor 10^n x \rfloor}{10^n}$

because:

$10^{n}x - 1 \leq \lfloor 10^{n} x \rfloor \leq 10^n x \implies x - \frac1{10^n} \leq a_n \leq x \implies x \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \leq x$

so $a_n \rightarrow x$

Answer (score 1):

Take $p_n=\dfrac {\lfloor10^nx\rfloor}{10^n}$, where $\lfloor X\rfloor$ is the greatest integer (floor) function.